# Where is sun.misc.FloatingDecimal?

Tags: java, rt.jar

src.zip in the jdk1.8.0_144 contains Float.java

That in turn refers to sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.  I cannot find that anywhere in src.zip? Can anyone tell me where it is?  I can find the source listed in grepcode: http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java/?v=source

but obviously, the code must exist for my library to be calling it.

Even odder, in class Float:

```
public static float parseFloat(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(s);
}
```

However, searching the code that I can see (admittedly, only jdk1.6) does not even have method FloatingDecimal.parseFloat.

Comment: try Float.valueOf(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not include it in `src.zip`.

Per the [JDK 8 README](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk-8-readme-2095712.html):

> Java programming language source files for all classes that make up
>   the Java core API (that is, sources files for the java.*, javax.* and
>   some org.* packages, **but not for com.sun.* packages**). This source
>   code is provided for informational purposes only, to help developers
>   learn and use the Java programming language. These files do not
>   include platform-specific implementation code and cannot be used to
>   rebuild the class libraries.

As you have found, you can get the source from 3rd party sources like Grepcode.